# How I consume vCloud API 1.5?

Tags: c#, asp.net, api

I am developnig web portal for company that provide cloud solutions.Using this portal Customer(companies that are using vCloud services)create/modify service subscriptions,Seek support assustance,pay bills etc.

Now I want to retrieve Virtual Datacenter Resources.
Retrieve and Display the following Service Subscriptions like  
**-CPU/gHz 

-RAM (GB) 

-Application and clients 

-Operating systems**

Also from this portal(website),SuperAdmin(Super User) can create/modify new company(organization) and set up this.etc

Admin can set up his organization

-Super User is service provider
-Admin is Company/Organization user

I am using Asp.net in this project.

I am asking about How can I do this?
By vCloud Director API?   (They are using VMWare vCloud Director)
Or by some SDK?
or any rest API is available to perform above task?

Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 1):

There is a [REST api](http://www.vmware.com/pdf/vcd_10_api_guide.pdf) that is available. You can found code that help you to use it on the vmware web site (you must get a free account).

You also must be award of the version of the vCloud you are using, the 1.0 isn't compatible with the 1.5 / 5.x

I also suggest you to use java, because there is lot more than just a REST api in java.
Without any help, using only the REST api was long. So I enjoyed using the java api-sdk.

Answer (score 0):

There is a SDK for C# also. You can take from there already created function to access the cloudDirectory infrastructure.
https://www.vmware.com/support/pubs/vcd_pubs.html